# Span / Hide input if selected Value is SMTH

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select with options and I have many inputs. I need to span ready input if I select in option for example  "USER" and hide it again if select another option.

```html
<form class="form-signup" action="admin_users.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">

                <div class="well well-sm">
                <h3 class="form-signin-heading"> Create

                <select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
                    <option value="1">User</option>
                    <option value="2">Admin</option>
                    <option value="3">Smth else</option>
                    <option value="4">Smth else of else</option>

                  </select>
                  </h3>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="İstifadəçi" value="first input" required autofocus>
</div>
<div> &nbsp </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ad" value="second input" required>
</div>
<div> &nbsp </div>

             <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='addUser' value='Create user' />
              </div>
               </form>
```

Comment: This is unclear, precise your question.

Comment: You may want to take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a minimal working example.

Comment: What do you mean by " I need to span ready ..." :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( "#selectlist" ).change(function(event) {
  if (this.value == 1 || this.value == 2) {
    $(".form-control").show();
  } else {
    $(".form-control").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signup" action="admin_users.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">

                    <div class="well well-sm">
                    <h3 class="form-signin-heading"> Create

                    <select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
                        <option value="1">User</option>
                        <option value="2">Admin</option>
                        <option value="3">Smth else</option>
                        <option value="4">Smth else of else</option>

                      </select>
                      </h3>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="İstifadəçi" value="first input" required autofocus>
    </div>
    <div> &nbsp </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ad" value="second input" required>
    </div>
    <div> &nbsp </div>

                 <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='addUser' value='Create user' />
                  </div>
                   </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i need!)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom attribute called `valueTie`.  When you update the select, your content will automatically update accordingly. What's nice is all you have to do is add another option and another div with the attribute `valueTie` and you're up and running with another option.

```js
$("#selectlist").change(function () {
  $("[valueTie]").hide()
  $("[valueTie='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
});

$("#selectlist").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signup" action="admin_users.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">
   <div class="well well-sm">
   <h3 class="form-signin-heading">
      Create
      <select id="selectlist" name="selectproduct" >
         <option value="1">User</option>
         <option value="2">Admin</option>
      </select>
   </h3>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12" valueTie="1">
         <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="İstifadəçi" value="first input" required autofocus>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12" valueTie="2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ad" value="second input" required>
      </div>
      <div> &nbsp </div>
      <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='addUser' value='Create user' />
   </div>
</form>
```